# Asterisk func odbc SQL query

Tags: asterisk

I want to achieve this query

```
select id from users where number like '%657356353%' or number like '%,657356353,%' or number like '%,657356353' or number like '657356353,%'
```

So I wrote the query in func_odbc like this

```
SELECT id from users where number like '%'${ARG2}'%' or number like '%,'${ARG2}',%' or number like '%,'${ARG2}'' or number like ''${ARG2}',%'
```

But the query does not work. I think there is an error there.

Comment: Please add relevant tags i.e. dbms, which language are you trying to use it in

Comment: The variable is ${ARG2} so let assume it is variable1 so I am trying to replicate this '%variable1%'

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it wrong it should have been written like this

SELECT id from users where number like '%${ARG2}%' or number like '%,${ARG2},%' or number like '%,${ARG2}' or number like '${ARG2},%' ) LIMIT 1